# JSPX adds <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to top of page, causes JS errors in IE6

Tags: javascript, jsp, jspx

When JSPX compiles, it automatically adds `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to top of file which causes some JavaScript code not to work on Internet Explorer 6.

How can I avoid it to add `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` in output file?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's where "X" in JSPX stands for. JSP in XML format. You've basically two options:

1. Use JSP instead of JSPX. This way you can output strict HTML instead of being forced to use XML/XHTML (recommended, unless you *really* need the advantages JSPX offers over JSP).
2. Fix the JavaScript code so that it doesn't error. You can do this by *either* moving it out of the JSPX file into its own `.js` file which you just include by `<script src="file.js"></script>` in the `<head>` (recommended), *or* by replacing all special/reserved XML characters like `&` and so on by XML entities like `&amp;`, *or* by placing all the JS code inside a `<![CDATA[` `]]>` block.

Comment: Notice that you may want to prefix <![CDATA[ and ]]> with a JavaScript line comment (//) for greater reliability in the face of tag soup, too.

Answer (score 0):

The XML declaration does not automatically cause your JavaScript to break. Rather you have JavaScript that relies on the idiosyncrasies of HTML which fail to hold true in XML. A specific example of such an assumption would be relying on case-insensitive behaviour for (element) names in HTML rather that case-sensitive behaviour in XML.